# Exception while Marshal.Copy()

Tags: c#, marshalling

for a faster access, I want to read the pixel of a Bitmap using a byte array. Therefore, I used the code provided here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.imaging.imagelockmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is my code:

```
private static int GetBitmapDataInByteArray(out byte[] bArr, ref System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp)
{
    int Length = -1;
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
        new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
    Length = System.Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmpData.Height;
    bArr = new byte[Length];

    /* Exception on this line: */
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, bArr, 0, Length);

    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    return Length;
}
```

I got a System.AccessViolationException - Reading or writing in protected memory.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: That `bmp` parameter doesn't need to be `ref` since you are not assigning to it (not your problem here, just a note)

Comment: runs fine on my machine

Comment: Try specifying the pixel format manually. I'd use `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`

Answer (score 1):

Philippe Pare was right. Specifying the pixelformat manually solves the problem. Maybe a cobflict between 32/64 bit?